# How do I get these conditions to apply properly in an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am a student going into software engineering and am taking my first computer science class on coding with java. I'm struggling to get my program to apply a certain set of conditions to a String in order to print a message regarding whether or not a user's input is indeed a valid double literal.

Here are the conditions:

1. Consists of exactly the following characters: ’+’, ’-’, ’.’ (decimal point), and ’0’ through ’9’
2. Either the ’+’ or ’-’ character may appear only as the first character
3. The ’.’ (decimal point) character must appear exactly once
4. All other characters must be the ’0’ through ’9’ characters

And here is my code:

```java
String doubleliteral;
int a;
char j;
char k;
char l;
char m;
char n;

System.out.print("Enter a valid four character double literal: ");
doubleliteral = keyboard.nextLine();

a = doubleliteral.length();
j = doubleliteral.charAt(0);
k = doubleliteral.charAt(1);
l = doubleliteral.charAt(2);
m = doubleliteral.charAt(3);
n = '.';

char i = (char)(a + 0);


if (i <= 4)
{
    System.out.print("\n" + doubleliteral + " is a valid four character double literal.");
}

else if ((j == '+') || (j == '-') || (j <= 9))
{
    
}

else if ((k <= 9))
{
    
}

else if (l <=9)
{
    
}

else if (m <= 9)
{
    
}

else if ((j != '.') && (k != '.') && (l != '.') && (m != '.'))
{
    System.out.print("\n" + doubleliteral + " is not a valid four character double literal.");  
}

else
{
    System.out.print("\n" + doubleliteral + " is not a valid four character double literal.");
}

keyboard.close();
```

I've been searching on the internet, in my textbook, and through my professor's presentations for about three days now trying to figure this out but nothing has come of it, please help.

Comment: To get to the point, this is exactly the sort of thing you should use a loop for.  Rather than assigning a `char` to variables for each `charAt()` position, just use a loop to check each character.  (The directions never say "must be exactly four characters in length" so only checking `charAt()` 0..3 is automatically wrong.)

Comment: I should have provided all of the instructions, the rest did specify for specifically four characters and also that we HAVE to use if statements to achieve the desired effect while storing the user input it in a String variable.

Comment: Using `if` statements does not preclude using a loop.  See the answer below, although if you really want to learn you should attempt a solution yourself without looking at the provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some psudo-code to get you in the right direction. I can't write your school answer here.

Loop through each character.  Special case the first.  Track if you have dot.

```
hasDot = false
for (i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
  ch = input[i]

  if (i === 0) {
    validChars = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-,+,.]
    // validChars must contain ch
    // if ch === dot, set hasDot = true
  }
  else {
    validChars = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.]
    // validChars must contain ch
    // if ch === dot and hasDot then error, else set hasDot = true  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few conditions you need to check to figure out the validity. Let's see one by one.

**`+` Or `-`**

There can be maximum one `+` or `-` operator and it has to be at the beginning of the given input.

So what you can do is, whenever you're getting a `+` or `-` operator, just check whether current index is `0` or not.

If it's not, then mark the input as invalid.

```
boolean isValid = true;
for(int i = 0; i < doubleliteral.length(); i++)
{
    if((doubleliteral[i] == '+' || doubleliteral[i] == '-'))
    {
        if(i != 0)
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // it's valid. 
        }
    }
}
```

**The `.` (decimal point) character**

There can be maximum one `.` character.

So you keep a count of it, check if it ever becomes more than `1`.

```
boolean isValid = true;
int dotCounter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < doubleliteral.length(); i++)
{
    if( doubleliteral[i] == '.')
    {
        if(dotCounter != 0)
        {
            isValid = false;
        }
        else dotCounter++;
    }
}
```

**Check if there's any character other than digits (o to 9)**

While traversing each character of the string, you can check if it's digit or not like following-

```
for(int i = 0; i < doubleliteral.length(); i++)
{
    if(Character.isDigit(doubleliteral.charAt(i)))
    {
        // it's a digit
    }
}
```

**Now if we combine everything it'll look like this:**

```
boolean isValid = true;
int dotCounter = 0;
int doubleliteralLength = doubleliteral.length();

for(int i = 0; i < doubleliteralLength; i++)
{
    if((doubleliteral[i] == '+' || doubleliteral[i] == '-'))
    {
        if(i != 0)
        {
            isValid = false;
            break;  // we don't need to check any further
        }
    }
    else if( doubleliteral[i] == '.')
    {
        if(dotCounter != 0)
        {
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
        else dotCounter++;
    }
    else if(Character.isDigit(doubleliteral.charAt(i)) != true)
    {
        // it's not a digit, not + or -, not .
        isValid = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(doubleliteralLength == 4 && isValid)
{
    System.out.print("\n" + doubleliteral + " is a valid four character double literal.");
}
else
{
    System.out.print("\n" + doubleliteral + " is not a valid four character double literal.");
}
```

Comment: Your solution is incorrect as it contains logic errors. For example, your method to find positive or negative symbol will return false if no symbol is found on the `String`. This is obviously wrong because "1.23" is a valid numeric value.

Comment: If no positive or negative symbol is found, then it'll not even enter into that condition. How will it return false? My code will show the example "1.23" as valid literal

Answer (score 0):

This question can be easily answered by using Regular Expressions and apply the expression to the inputted `String` object. Although this question is technically correct, it is not correct for the lesson your professor is teaching (which I am guessing is String parsing).

That said, here are my clues to you:

- Symbols (+ or -) can only be present at character index 0.
- The (decimal) ASCII values for numbers 0-9 are 48-57. Therefore, an ASCII
  value outside this range that is not a "+", "-", or "." (43, 45, or
  46 respectively) is an illegal character.

The next thing you need to do is write down a few combinations of characters and test them out manually. For example:

- 1.34 // invalid (first character must be the sign)
- .123 // invalid (first character must be the sign)
- -.98 // valid
- -0.1 // valid
- +2.3 // valid
- 2.+6 // invalid
- 4.3- // invalid
- 30-4 // invalid
- +23. // valid (by your requirements, but it should not be)
- +0.- // invalid

All of the above contain nothing but valid characters, but not all are correctly formatted. Once you test these out, you should try using other non-numeric characters.

Your code should be something like this (in psedocode)

```
IF STRING LENGTH > 4, ERROR (String has too many characters)
IF PERIOD COUNT > 1, ERROR // See * note
IF CHAR AT 0 NOT VALID, ERROR (Special case for symbols, period, or numbers)
IF CHAR AT X NOT VALID, ERROR (index 1-3 can only be numbers or the period)
IF CHAR AT 3 == ., ERROR (Last index cannot be the period)
PRINT STING MESSAGE
```

(*) My suggestion is to use a loop operation to count the number of times the period appears on the String. There are other ways to do this, but my guess is that they are not related to your current lesson. Some of those alternative methods are using regular expressions, using Streams API, using recursion, or using 3rd party libraries. Stay away from any of those solutions.

If all the tests passed, then the only thing that will be printed out will be the message containing the valid numeric string.

Last hint: Do all of the CHAR AT evaluations in a single pass (i.e. loop through your String (array of characters) to determine if the character at any given position is valid. A multiple pass solution is OK, just not elegant or effective.

## The solution

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumericStringEvaluator {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a valid four character double literal: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.next();
        scanner.close();

        if (input.length() > 4) {
            System.err.println("String must be exactly 4 characters");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        //1. Consists of exactly the following characters: ’+’, ’-’ ...
        //2. Either the ’+’ or ’-’ character may appear only as the first character
        if (input.charAt(0) != '+' && input.charAt(0) != '-') {
            System.err.println("Invalid character at index 0: " + input.charAt(0));
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int periodCount = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            //1. Consists of ... ’.’ ...
            if (c == '.') {
                periodCount++; //3. The ’.’ (decimal point) character must appear exactly once
            }
            // 1. Consists of ...    and ’0’ through ’9’
            // 4. All other characters must be the ’0’ through ’9’ characters
            // ASCII values for number are 48-57 (anything outside the range is not a number)
            // and the special characters have been accounted for already
            else if (c < 48 || c > 57) {
                System.err.println("Invalid character at index " + i + ": " + input.charAt(i));
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        
        // At this point, every character in the string has been validated (no errors found)
        
        //3. The ’.’ (decimal point) character must appear exactly once
        if (periodCount != 1) {
            System.err.println("Decimal point appears more than once in numeric String.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
             System.out.print("\n" + input + " is a valid four character double literal.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have gotten to the point of having a valid set of nested if else statements in my code and a for loop at the beginning to check each individual character position but am struggling to get the compiler to read any inputs that are more or less than four.  Can you help?

Comment: @Fried_Sauer.Kraut I posted a solution that should satisfy your assignment. Notice that I explicitly checked the requirement for the first character, and then used a single loop to evaluate the characters from index 1 thru 3 exclusive. If the loop finishes without an error, the numeric string is valid (unless more than one period)